# Remove row if the one column list is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I remove all the rows if the value of one column list is empty?

[image]

so the end result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are empty lists, cast them to boolean, we will get `True`s for non-empty values and filter them using [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['ids'].astype(bool)]
```

But if empty strings `()` compare for not equal:

```
df = df[df['ids'].ne('()')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df[df['ids'].map(len)>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df["id"] = [x for x in df["id"] if len(x) >= 1]
```